# Insert a function into javascript object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I tried to insert a function into javascript object but I get

> > undefined

This is supposed to return a message into div.

I would like to do it the first way, but here is the both way I tried :

```js
var errorMessage = {
     empty: function(message){"<div class='field'><div class='csv'><span class='icon'></span><label class='manual' id='error-message'>" + message + "</label></div></div>"
    }
 };

console.log(errorMessage.empty("Hello"));
```

I also try this way

```js
function errorMessage(message){
    "<div class='field'><div class='csv'><span class='icon'></span><label class='manual' id='error-message'>" + message + "</label></div></div>"

}

console.log(errorMessage("hello"))
```

Comment: There is no return statement on the function.

Comment: What do you expect the function to do? It's literally just a string literal in a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) of the value literally.

> The `return` statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

```js
var errorMessage = {
        empty: function (message) {
            return "<div class='field'><div class='csv'><span class='icon'></span><label class='manual' id='error-message'>" + message + "</label></div></div>";
        }
    };

console.log(errorMessage.empty("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `function` needs to return the value

```js
var errorMessage = {
     empty: function(message){
        return "<div class='field'><div class='csv'><span class='icon'></span><label class='manual' id='error-message'>" + message + "</label></div></div>";
    }
 };

console.log(errorMessage.empty("Hello"));
```